# Calling node.js webserver from scheduler process using heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am using Heroku hosting and have setup a node.js webserver.  I now want to run another node script that will send periodic POST requests to the node.js webserver utilizing the Heroku scheduler.  When I'm running on my own machine I run the script that generates the POST request as follows:

```
var request = require('request');
...
request.post("http://localhost:5000/submit").form(some_json_data);
```

However when I want to deploy to Heroku I want to ensure I want to use the correct HOST and PORT settings (I'm sure the port the webserver runs on won't be 5000 for example).  How can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scheduler job will spin up a new dyno, so if you want to make a post, you'll have to do it to `yourapp.heorkuapp.com` or `yourcustomdomain.com`. You therefore do need to care about the port.

Comment: Thanks Will.  I suppose the question then becomes, how do you then configure different urls for different environment (dev, uat, prod etc.) using heroku and node.js?  What's the recommended approach?

Comment: I'd probably try having the scheduler job take the domain as an argument